# How to find and read file using wild cards with VBscript?

Tags: file, vbscript, io

I am trying unsuccessfully to read an XML file (The file name is change in each computer).
How it possible to read the file using wild card?
for example: `D:\Logs\*.xml`

Script:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Logs\*.xml", ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "server1 ", "server889 ")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\Logs\*.xml", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Closeenter code here
```

Comment: Is the name of the file is really *.xml or is it just a place holder? What happens than you run your code, nothing or an error?

Comment: No is not the reall name of the file, But because the file name is change in each computer I must use wild card, like: "D:\Logs\*.xml".

I get the next error : "Bad file name or number"

Comment: @MrMush `*` (asterisk) is  _reserved character_, see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no *wild card* in `VBScript`. Repeat your group of statements for each element in `Files` collection of `Folder` object obtained by `GetFolder` Method:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Logs")

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each oFile in colFiles
    If UCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.name)) = "XML" Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(oFile.Path, ForReading)
        strText = objFile.ReadAll
        objFile.Close
        If Instr( 1, strText, "server1 ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            strNewText = Replace(strText, "server1 ", "server889 ", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
            Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(oFile.Path, ForWriting)
            objFile.WriteLine strNewText
            objFile.Close
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Resource: [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Not entirely true. Some `FileSystemObject` methods do support wildcards in specific cases (example: [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)). However, wildcards are not supported for opening files (or for iterating over a collection of files).